# Getting Stanford NLP to recognise named entities with multiple words

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

First off let me say that I am a complete newbie with NLP. Although, as you read on, that is probably going to become strikingly apparent.

I'm parsing Wikipedia pages to find all mentions of the page title. I do this by going through the CorefChainAnnotations to find "proper" mentions - I then assume that the most common ones are talking about the page title. I do it by running this:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,coref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    String content = "Abraham Lincoln was an American politician and lawyer who served as the 16th President of the United States from March 1861 until his assassination in April 1865. Lincoln led the United States through its Civil War—its bloodiest war and perhaps its greatest moral, constitutional, and political crisis.";
    Annotation document = new Annotation(content);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
        List<CorefChain.CorefMention> corefMentions = cc.getMentionsInTextualOrder();
        for (CorefChain.CorefMention cm : corefMentions) {
            if (cm.mentionType == Dictionaries.MentionType.PROPER) {
                log("Proper ref using " + cm.mentionSpan + ", " + cm.mentionType);
            }
        }
    }
```

This returns:

```
Proper ref using the United States
Proper ref using the United States
Proper ref using Abraham Lincoln
Proper ref using Lincoln
```

I know already that "Abraham Lincoln" is definitely what I am looking for and I can surmise that because "Lincoln" appears a lot as well then that must be another way of talking about the main subject. (I realise right now the most common named entity is "the United States", but once I've fed it the whole page it works fine).

This works great until I have a page like "Gone with the Wind". If I change my code to use that:

```
String content = "Gone with the Wind has been criticized as historical revisionism glorifying slavery, but nevertheless, it has been credited for triggering changes to the way African-Americans are depicted cinematically.";
```

then I get no Proper mentions back at all. I suspect this is because none of the words in the title are recognised as named entities.

Is there any way I can get Stanford NLP to recognise "Gone with the Wind" as an already-known named entity? From looking around on the internet it seems to involve training a model, but I want this to be a known named entitity just for this single run and I don't want the model to remember this training later.

I can just imagine NLP experts rolling their eyes at the awfulness of this approach, but it gets better! I came up with the great idea of changing any occurences of the page title to "Thingamijig" before passing the text to Stanford NLP, which works great for "Gone with the Wind" but then fails for "Abraham Lincoln" because (I think) the NER longer associates "Lincoln" with "Thingamijig" in the corefMentions.

In my dream world I would do something like:

```
    pipeline.addKnownNamedEntity("Gone with the Wind");
```

But that doesn't seem to be something I can do and I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit a dictionary with any phrases you want and have them recognized as named entities.

```
java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -ner.additional.regexner.mapping additional.rules -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

additional.rules

```
Gone With The Wind    MOVIE    MISC    1
```

Note that the columns above should be tab-delimited.  You can have as many lines as you'd like in the `additional.rules` file.

One warning, EVERY TIME that token pattern occurs it will be tagged.

More details here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at my question! When I import the additional.rules file, is it just for this single run or does the data get kept over for other runs of the CoreNLP?

Comment: If you build the pipeline with that option, it will use it for all runs of the pipeline.

Comment: Make sure to specify the rules with props.setProperty("ner.additional.regexner.mapping", "additional.rules") in your code

Comment: Yep I did that. Thank you very much!